# How to build a MEX-file in MATLAB?

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I need to use the following function in MATLAB code:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float xFit_1931( float wave )
{
float t1 = (wave-442.0f)*((wave<442.0f)?0.0624f:0.0374f);
float t2 = (wave-599.8f)*((wave<599.8f)?0.0264f:0.0323f);
float t3 = (wave-501.1f)*((wave<501.1f)?0.0490f:0.0382f);
return 0.362f*expf(-0.5f*t1*t1) + 1.056f*expf(-0.5f*t2*t2)
- 0.065f*expf(-0.5f*t3*t3);
}
float yFit_1931( float wave )
{
float t1 = (wave-568.8f)*((wave<568.8f)?0.0213f:0.0247f);
float t2 = (wave-530.9f)*((wave<530.9f)?0.0613f:0.0322f);
return 0.821f*exp(-0.5f*t1*t1) + 0.286f*expf(-0.5f*t2*t2);
}
float zFit_1931( float wave )
{
float t1 = (wave-437.0f)*((wave<437.0f)?0.0845f:0.0278f);
float t2 = (wave-459.0f)*((wave<459.0f)?0.0385f:0.0725f);
return 1.217f*exp(-0.5f*t1*t1) + 0.681f*expf(-0.5f*t2*t2);
}
```

This function is coded in C language so I tried to build a MEX-file but I got this error message:

```
>> mex CMfunction.c
Building with 'lcc-win32'.
Error using mex
c:\users\ya7yawii\appdata\local\temp\mex_1695753636261_3832\cmfunction.obj
.text: undefined reference to '_expf'
Specified export _mexFunction is not defined
Missing exports. Aborting
```

Comment: Please check out the [high level description](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/what-you-need-to-build-mex-files.html) of building mex extensions, and then use the [basic example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/build-an-executable-mex-file.html) as a starting point for your project.

Comment: "mexFunction is not defined" You need to write a function `mexFunction` if you want to create a MEX-file (see Robert's links). But you can also compile this as a regular shared object (DLL on Windows) and use [`loadlibrary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html) to call the functions.

Answer (score 0):

I have just rewritten these functions in matlab code using the mathematical equations in the following paper [Simple Analytic Approximations to the CIE XYZ
Color Matching Functions](http://jcgt.org/published/0002/02/01/paper.pdf).

```
function int = xFit_1931(wave)
t1 = 0.0624.*(1-heaviside(wave-442.0))+0.0374.*heaviside(wave-442.0);
t2 = 0.0264.*(1-heaviside(wave-599.8))+0.0323.*heaviside(wave-599.8);
t3 = 0.0490.*(1-heaviside(wave-501.1))+0.0382.*heaviside(wave-501.1);
int = 0.362.*exp(-0.5.*((wave-442.0).*t1).^2)+1.056.*exp(-0.5.*((wave-599.8).*t2).^2)-0.065.*exp(-0.5.*((wave-501.1).*t3).^2);
end

function int = yFit_1931(wave)
t1 = 0.0213.*(1-heaviside(wave-568.8))+0.0247.*heaviside(wave-568.8);
t2 = 0.0613.*(1-heaviside(wave-530.9))+0.0322.*heaviside(wave-530.9);
int = 0.821.*exp(-0.5.*((wave-568.8).*t1).^2)+0.286.*exp(-0.5.*((wave-530.9).*t2).^2);
end

function int = zFit_1931(wave)
t1 = 0.0845.*(1-heaviside(wave-437.0))+0.0278.*heaviside(wave-437.0);
t2 = 0.0385.*(1-heaviside(wave-459.0))+0.0725.*heaviside(wave-459.0);
int = 1.217.*exp(-0.5.*((wave-437.0).*t1).^2)+0.681.*exp(-0.5.*((wave-459.0).*t2).^2);
end
```